# How to put URL link in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to put link like that I made that link Sell Items but I failed. I want it on the dashboard only but when I view the Store menu it has a Sell Items link also.

[image]

```
if(isset($products) && $products) {
        foreach ($products as $product => $value) {
                $new_description = strlen($products[$product]->description) > 50 ? substr($products[$product]->description,0,50)."..." : $products[$product]->description;
            $price = $products[$product]->option[0]->price;
            $option = "";
            // dd($products[$product]->option);

    if(Auth::check()) {
        if(Auth::user()->id == $products[$product]->seller_id) {
     echo'      <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a href="'.URL::to('product/editproduct').'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Continue shopping
                </a>
            </div>';

        }
    }
```

In if(Auth::check()) that is my Link code of Sell Items. But I ended up like this one..
[image]

Comment: Don’t wrap it in a `<div>` with a class of `col-xs-6`.

Comment: The same result :/ @MartinBean

Comment: Try url() . '/product/editproduct'

Comment: You ended up like this, but what did you expect? I don't get the issue - sorry..